# Data mining outlook e-mail bodies

Tags: powershell, outlook

A while ago I went through and starting using the script guys get-outlookInbox which worked great with Data mining Subjects, however, I'm now trying to basically do the same thing but by trying to do this with bodies.

Originally I was importing the custom script from the script guys: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/05/26/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox/

Using the line

```
$inbox | Where-Object { $_.subject -match 'x'} | Where-Object { ($_.ReceivedTime -gt "06 11 2017") -and ($_.ReceivedTime -lt "10 10 2018") } | Group-Object -Property senderName -NoElement | Sort-Object count
```

I've tried changing `$_.subject` to `$_.body` however it seems that the original script doesn't pull body contents, i'm somewhat stuck here and was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not available is because the original script does not select the body. In order to get the body of the message you will need to change the original script to include the body.

Change:

> Get-OutlookInbox.ps1

Change the line from:

```
$folder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName
```

To:

```
$folder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName, body
```

Comment: returns the error Exception calling "GetNamespace" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This operation failed because the 
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)."

Comment: Make sure if you are running powershell as administrator that you run outlook as administrator as well.